# Simple LINQ to Entities update throwing 'Timeout expired'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, linq-to-entities, timeout

The simple method below is throwing a timeout error and I can't figure out why this might be. This may be executed in multiple times in succession and I'm wondering if this could be the cause?

```
public static Boolean UpdateMessageState(int messageId, int stateId, string message)
{
    var repo = new MailItemRepository();
    try
    {
        var objTask = repo.GetMailByMailId(messageId);

        objTask.State = stateId;
        objTask.Result = message;
        repo.Save();

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Info(ex.Message);
        logger.Info(ex.InnerException);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Error trace:

```
2012-07-02 15:26:38.1002|INFO|EF.Methods.MailMethods.UpdateMessageState|System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
```

***EDIT:***

I've removed LINQ from the equation and now have this as UpdateMessageState

```
public static Boolean UpdateMessageState(int messageId, int stateId, string message)
    {

        var success = true;

        var conn =
            new SqlConnection(
                "Data Source=...");

        try
        {

            //logger.Info(String.Format("S1:messageId={0},stateId={1},message={2}", messageId, stateId, message));

            var cmdPers = new SqlCommand("procMailQueueStatusUpdate", conn)
                              {
                                  CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                              };

            cmdPers.Parameters.Add("@MessageId", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmdPers.Parameters.Add("@StateId", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmdPers.Parameters.Add("@Message", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1);

            cmdPers.Parameters["@MessageId"].Value = messageId;
            cmdPers.Parameters["@StateId"].Value = stateId;
            cmdPers.Parameters["@Message"].Value = message;

            conn.Open();
            cmdPers.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Info(ex.Message);
            success = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return success;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't return true or false, it's obsolete and now days bad design. Make just a void instead.

Comment: @abatishchev Thanks for the tip. Do you have any ideas what might be causing my issue?

Comment: Is `GetMailByMailId` a mapped function? Can you ran it from SSMS? Is it running fine? Can you run a plain query (for example, calling this function) using ADO.NET, will it run fine?

Comment: Can you please show us your linq to entity query located in your `repo.GetMailByMailId(messageId)` method?

Comment: @Aducci I have now taken LINQ out of the equation and added the code above (in 'EDIT') - it's still timing out despite the SP running fine when executed manually.

Comment: Have you tried using a sql profiler to see the exact sql that is getting passed to your DB?

Comment: @Aducci Yes, the update SP is executed with the correct parameters.

Comment: Nick, keep in mind the time out in SSMS is very high (actually its unlimited by default).  While the timeout by default in the .net data connector is much lower (15 seconds).  So if the stored proc is long running SSMS wont balk at all, but the sql connection in code will

Comment: Nick, going back to @Aducci's suggestion, use SQL Profiler to trace 'SQL Statement Completed' events, have it bring back TextData, and filter the Duration column to be a reasonably long time (10 seconds) so we can see the sql that is actually causing the timeout.

Comment: Also, is this NOT producing a timeout for certain parameter values?

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that sql sever is just responding a little slower than you are expecting.  This can be caused by several things (memory pressure, disk IO, resource waits, network latency, etc).

Just increase the timeout on your connection and you should be golden. You can make this change adding the "Connect Timeout" keyword into your current connection string

http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords

i.e.

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Connect Timeout=60
```

If this fails, try increasing the command timeout.  When using ADO you can do it as follows.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{            
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
    cmd.Connection = con;
}
```

To set this property in linq to entities use the following method

```
using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
{
  db.CommandTimeout = 60;
}
```